# MySQL Num Rows Warning in if statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the error: `Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in.... on line ..`

Please can you tell me what I am doing wrong to cause this. I don't believe that I am.

```
        if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Likes WHERE `postID` = '$postID' AND `userID` = '$accountID'")) < 1) {
            exit("Cant like a post twice");
        }
```

Comment: mysql_query returns boolean FALSE if the query causes an error for ANY reason. Passing its results to mysql_num_rows will cause this error as num_rows expects a statement handle, but is getting that error condition FALSE instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also simplify your sql by selecting the count directly from the database, which is more efficient then selecting all the rows, and then calculating the count

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Likes WHERE 
                      `postID` = '$postID' AND `userID` = '$accountID'");

// check for mysql errors
if (mysql_error()) {
    die(mysql_error());
}

list($count) = mysql_fetch_row($res);
```

Answer (score 2):

As advised by yes123, `mysql_error()` will give you the reason. Two comments however:

- You shouldn't use `mysql_num_rows()` to count a result set. Instead, issue a `SELECT COUNT(*)` and check the returned value. This is way more efficient.
- There is a better solution for your specific problem: just add a UNIQUE key to the (postID, userID) fields, and you can skip this test. Instead, just try to INSERT your new record, and check the `mysql_errno()` value after that. If it returns 0, then the insert worked; if it returns 1062 (ER_DUP_ENTRY), the insert failed because a similar record already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Never nest call like that.

Run before a

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Likes WHERE 
                      `postID` = '$postID' AND `userID` = '$accountID'") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

to check what is the error.

To check for errors I prefer this notation (as stated in the comment)

```
   $res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Likes WHERE 
                          `postID` = '$postID' AND `userID` = '$accountID'");

   if(!is_resource($res))
     die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: This ugly `or die()` error handling needs to die. Or actually, the `mysql_*` functions need to die - at least unless they are used with a proper wrapper.

Comment: @thief +1. I never use that. I just used here because is short

Answer (score 1):

First I hope you have correctly escaped your $postID and $accountID in your query as if not you open a big door to SQL injection.

Then you should check the result of your query before putting it directly in the mysql_num_rows. I suppose you have an error in you query (or connection) and then you end up to call mysq_num_rows(false).
Try to check if there's an error returned by your query with mysql_error.
Does this give you any more information ?